# Docker Remote API with Weave

Tags: docker, weave, docker-api

I am trying to create a docker container using Docker Remote APIv1.23

I am not able to create docker container in Weave.

I have started the weave-proxy with the following command:

```
weave launch-proxy -H tcp://0.0.0.0:12375 -H     unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock
```

and in the post body of container creation call I am setting this enviornment

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://0.0.0.0:12375
```

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Instead of hitting the docker daemon on docker port(in my case 4242) hit the weave proxy port (in this case 12375)

```
For example: docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:12375 run .....
```

When using the Remote API, use 12375 port instead of 4242. 
There is no need to set any environment variable related to weave.